# How can I start Nautilus on Xubuntu / XFCE via the shortcuts in the XFCE panels?

Tags: nautilus, xfce, filemanager, thunar, xdg-open

I am on Xubuntu 13.10 and just installed and activated Nautilus as the default file manager.

I'd like to use the current default file manager (whichever that might be) when I click on my panel shortcut to open any folder shortcut and so on.

I want to try to avoid to re-define the shortcuts for the file manager. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to simply open the current default file manager (in a sense of a macro) on Xfce from a shortcut.

First of, you need to install another file manager:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Then open the (system) **Settings** and click on **Preferred Applications**. Under the tab **Tools**, choose 'Nautilus' for the file manager.

For the shortcut in a bar on your desktop, use `xdg-open .` (mind the dot at the end) as the command. You don't have to write `nautilus`. Example:

[image]

(Just fyi, I googled quite a bit for this, hence I made this quick Q&A.)

**EDIT**

I use Synapse on Xubuntu since it is, as of this writing on 2014-04-27, again available on the core PPA of the developer. [Looking back, I found using Nautilus quite annoying since it intervened with Synapse's handling of MIME types. Ultimately, I went back to Thunar.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404010/why-does-synapse-use-nautilus-for-all-file-types-instead-of-the-default-applicat)

Answer (score 1):

you have to install the package called exo-utils.
`sudo apt-get install exo-utils`

Then press Alt+F2 and run the command `exo-preferred-applications`.

In Preferred Applications, click on the Utilities tab, and under File Manager, select Nautilus. (You must install Nautilus first, if you haven't already.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `Directory Menu` panel plug-in which seems to do what you ask. In the plug-in's `Properties` you can define the `Base dir` to whichever you prefer.