# Switched to xubuntu-desktop, nautilus glitches

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, nautilus, xfce, thunar

I've recently switched from unity to xfce4, by installing through the package manager with:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Sometimes when using xfce4 desktop a glitch happened where I was unable to change my wallpaper, for instance. So I decided to purge unity with

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop unity-*
```

However, it seems that I might still have many duplicate applications from Unity. Since then I have narrowed the annoying glitch to nautilus starting (xfce4 uses thunar by default), and it seems to be solved by killing it:

```
nautilus -q
```

Is there a clean solution for this? Is it ok to uninstall nautilus or whatever came with the default unity-desktop?

Comment: I suggest you to completely uninstall Nautilus. After that, [reinstall it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403892/how-can-i-start-nautilus-on-xubuntu-xfce-via-the-shortcuts-in-the-xfce-panels). Maybe Nautilus is "missing" unity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we decide to change graphical interface (from Ubuntu to Xubuntu e.g) some apps, although keep working at newer GUI, are natively bound to original environment, so they may become unstable after that.

So it's Nautilus. It's a good practice to reinstall it to grant a better performance.

```
sudo apt remove --purge nautilus
sudo apt install nautilus
```